# How do I change the color of Semantic UI icons?

Tags: css, colors, semantic-ui

I can make thumbs up icon with the code

`<i class="thumbs up icon large"></i>`

But how can I change the color from black to gray? I do it for a chrome extension and I add the CSS this way in the `manifest.js`:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],

        "css": [ "tab/layouts/style.css", "app/lib/semantic.min.css" ],
        "js": [ "common/owconstants.js", "common/OWprotocol.js", "3rdparty/jquery-1.10.2.min.js", "3rdparty/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js", "3rdparty/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js", "common/common.js", "tab/sidebars.js", "tab/communication.js", "tab/syncobject.js", "tab/popup.js", "tab/authorization.js", "tab/userinfo.js", "tab/annotation.js", "tab/usercard.js", "tab/userlist.js", "tab/notifications.js", "tab/friendlist.js", "tab/injection.js", "tab/drops.js", "tab/chat.js", "tab/tracking.js", "tab/keywords.js", "tab/tabscript.js", "app/lib/semantic.min.js"]
    }
],
```

Comment: Add your css to the question please.

Comment: @GarethWhittaker I added the code that loads the CSS. All my CSS is externally provided from semantic-ui.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply:

```
color: gray; // or any suitable color code, e.g. #808080
```

to one of the existing classes `thumbs up icon large` if suitable, or add a new class of your own and apply styling to this instead:

HTML

```
<i class="thumbs up icon large own-class"></i>
```

Stylesheet

```
.own-class {
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Some icons do not have outline. How can we give outline style? For example for unlock icon, asterisk icon do not support outline feature.

Answer (score 8):

You can also apply: `<i class="red users icon"></i>` .For more information about semantic-ui I recommend to visit this doc http://semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html#/definition

Answer (score 0):

For White:
`<i class="bars icon" style="color:#ffffff !important" id="rmenu"></i>e`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <i class="large **black** inverted alarm icon"></i>
```

define color name if you are using semantic.